# Generate random floating point number

Tags: python

Right now I'm working on making Python "type" on your screen (I was feeling bored and experimental), and I got this far on my own, but I can't find any way to use decimals in my script, as Python only accepts whole numbers for randint().

```
#include <stdio.h>;
import sys;
import time;
import os;
import random;
os.system("clear");

script = "I just really need to type something right now. I'm not sure why, but I really feel like typing on the Chromebook right now. It seems kinda weird, but I like doing this. It helps me practice what I'm doing. I've noticed that I'm a lot worse at typing lately, and I don't know why. Maybe it's because I've been working with a chunky keyboard, and these Chromebook keyboards are extremely thin. Yup, this is actually entertaining for me. I'm not exactly sure why I want to do this, but I just do. It's almost addicting to me, and I don't know why.\n";

for i in range(0, 587):
sys.stdout.write(str(scripti));
sys.stdout.flush();
time_num = random.randint(0.1, 0.4);
time.sleep(time_num);
```

The output I get is:

```
ITraceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
time_num = random.randint(0.1, 0.4);
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/random.py", line 242, in randint
return self.randrange(a, b+1)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/random.py", line 187, in randrange
raise ValueError, "non-integer arg 1 for randrange()"
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Don't tell me how to make this simpler, as this was just for learning.

Comment: Did you check the function name? [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)... Does it ring a bell?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: He's trying to give you a h`int`. :)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. BTW, semicolons on the end of statements is only needed in Python if you're putting multiple statements on a line (then you need to use `;` to separate the statements). However, the preferred Python coding style is to put one statement per line. Semicolons can come in handy if you're doing stuff in the interactive interpreter, but try to avoid using them in actual Python programs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you use the random uniform distribution instead? In this case you can get non integer number values. Use:

```
import random
random.uniform(0.1,0.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use randint, you could do `time_num = randint(1, 4)/10`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(0, 587):
```

... nothing is indented there (unless you didn't post the indents in the question).. so it's practically **useless**

For the `time_num` Variable you could cast it like this:

```
time_num = double(random.randrange(1, 4) \ 10
```

you must be trying to get it in `milliseconds` because python uses Seconds for the `time import`

but you could also rephrase it like instead of using `randint` use `random.randrange(#1, #2)`

And I don't know the `sys import` but you used this -> `sys.stdout.write(str(scripti));`

**BUT** your variable is named `"script"`.........

Comment: Good call on the lack of indentation in the OP. But `double` should be `float` (or just use `10.0` as the divisor if this code isn't for Python 3). Also, the division operator is `/` slash, not `\` backslash. And your parentheses aren't closed.

Comment: <--- not really a python guy xD, but thnx